# What does the -l directive do?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

I know that -f and -d will ignore files and directories, but what is it -l for?

Comment: Alex, things must be getting bad when its easier to ask a Q on SO than to look up the page in the documentation, google `apache rewritecond` and click on the first link.  :-(

Comment: Newbies are allowed to do this, but a 1+14+67er gets teased :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> **'-l'** (is symbolic link)
>   Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a symbolic link.

Comment: how is a symbolic link different from a file or dir?

Comment: A link is kind of a special file. Though the `-f` and `-d` should work fine for links as well. Maybe `-l` is added as precaution.